# Asking how to download MSDN ISOs when you lost media but have key

Tags: discussion, scope

I wonder if the following question would be on-topic on SO.

> As a former MSDN subscriber, I have had access to Microsoft software
>   on a perpetual basis. I had dowloaded a few ISOs (for example Windows
>   2012) for development and testing our software, however, we are moving
>   to better hardware and lost our ISOs but still have our keys from our
>   subscription.
>
> How do I, as a perpetual license holder, download the missing media
>   for MSDN?

Or is this question off-topic?

The reason I thought this question was relevant for Stack Overflow is because it deals with MSDN and associated media and licensing, which is relevant to Microsoft software developers. I can also see how this is relevant to Super User.

Comment: Maybe more oriented towards SuperUser?

Comment: Sounds logical. Will I be flogged if I post this same question on meta.superuser.com?

Comment: I doubt it.  Asking a question on their Meta shouldn't get you into trouble.

Comment: Very doubtful you could ask for help downloading "missing media".  You can only download files.  Like an ISO image.  Do consider using the MSDN concierge service for assistance.

Comment: @SwisherSweet I would wait for further input. Then you can delete this and ask about it over there if needed

Comment: If you paid for it, why not contact their support? What problem will random users be able to help you with regarding your subscription with Microsoft?

Comment: Thanks, but it does get you downvotes, as evident from this question...  :(

Comment: Relevant meta.SU question [Why was this question closed and what should I do about it?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6615/why-was-this-question-closed-and-what-should-i-do-about-it).  The source question was deleted, but the meta question suggests it is a similar topic

Comment: Downvotes on Meta mean "Disagree" or "No", not "Bad Quality".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So a question like you describe is absolutely not on-topic on Stack Overflow.  In addition to not being a programming question, it is essentially a resource request (which are off-topic as well).

Questions about computer software and hardware could be on-topic on Super User, but a quick search of their meta, you might find [Why was this question closed and what should I do about it?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6615/why-was-this-question-closed-and-what-should-i-do-about-it).  Now the original question that inspired that meta post was deleted, the title suggests it could be a similar question - that is "I lost my software, where can I legally download it".

The answer to that question from a high rep SU user is that questions of that sort are essentially considered "shopping questions", which are off-topic there.

However, if you keep looking, you might also find this post on SU: [Where can I download Windows 8 legally, from Microsoft?](https://superuser.com/questions/493766/where-can-i-download-windows-8-legally-from-microsoft), which was closed but then reopened by a single user (I believe a former moderator on that site), and received a far bit of positive attention.

There are also several other similar questions on the site that are either opened or closed.  Given the mix reception,  I think the only possible answer that the SO community can provide is "*it might be on topic on SU, you'd have to ask them* (i.e, you'd have to ask on their meta)".